# ServiceStack - When returning an HttpError, the response content-type does not respect Accept header in request

Tags: servicestack

I have a service action that returns an HttpError if something goes wrong while processing the request. If I set the request Accept header to text/plain, the Content-Type of the response is text/html. If I set the request Accept header to text/html, the Content type of the response is text/plain. I don't understand why the content-type of the response does not respect the Accept header on the request?

```
public object Delete(MyRequest request) 
{
   // Some processing ...
   
   
  return new HttpError(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Invalid id");
}
```